# Finding more than one Min and Max within Dynamic Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting a result as shown in image.

I am getting 2 range of values

1)from 79996 to 80000

2)from 001001 to 001003

So, i want 2 minimum values 79996 and 001001 and 2 max values 80000 and 001003.

the values or the range is not fixed and there can be more than 1 range.

Is it possible!!!!

Please help...

[image]

Comment: What is the criteria for range bounds? Why not to build N ranges , for example 79996..79998 or 001003 ... 80000 ?

Answer (score 1):

This query will select only bounds of continuous ranges (sequential integers, you should cast char type columns to integer before use this):

```
select distinct tr_no,
case 
when left_ind = 'gap' and right_ind = 'seq' then 'RANGE_MIN'
when left_ind = 'seq' and right_ind = 'gap' then 'RANGE_MAX'
else 'MIN-MAX' end as bound_type
from
(
select job_no, tr_no,
case when abs(tr_no - PREV_TR) = 1 then 'seq' else 'gap' as left_ind,
case when abs(NEXT_TR - tr_no) = 1 then 'seq' else 'gap' as right_ind
from 
(
select job_no, tr_no, 
LEAD(tr_no) over (order by tr_no) as NEXT_TR,
LAG(tr_no) over (order by tr_no) as PREV_TR
from mytable
) m1
) m2
where left_ind = 'gap' or right_ind = 'gap'
```